# OptionalDataException with Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, io, objectinputstream

I have run in to an issue with serializing an object containing instances of bufferedImage and an enum, more specifically with the OptionalDataException. I've tried to identify the error all day but I simply can't pinpoint it and would appreciate your help.

It writes the objects fine, but when reading I run in to the exception. The documentation defines the exception as I have got spare primitive data in the stream, but I can't figure out why, where or how it got there.

**Code:**

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {

    out.defaultWriteObject();
    ImageIO.write(preview, "png", out);
    ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "png", out);
    ImageIO.write(original, "png", out);

    out.writeInt(tags.size());
    for (String string : tags) {
        out.writeObject(string);
    }

    out.writeInt(versions.size());
    for (Entry<FiltersEnum, BufferedImage> entry : versions.entrySet()) {
        out.writeObject(entry.getKey().name());
        ImageIO.write(entry.getValue(), "png", out);
    }

}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    preview = ImageIO.read(in);
    thumbnail = ImageIO.read(in);
    original = ImageIO.read(in);

    tags = new TreeSet<String>();
    int len = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tags.add((String) in.readObject());
    }

    versions = new TreeMap<FiltersEnum, BufferedImage>();
    len = in.readInt();
    try {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            FiltersEnum key = FiltersEnum.valueOf((String) in.readObject());
        versions.put(key, ImageIO.read(in));
        }
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Called from:**

```
imageList.add((ExtendedImage) in.readObject());
```

**Trace:**

```
java.io.OptionalDataException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1302)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at model.ExtendedImage.readObject(ExtendedImage.java:214)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at model.Library.loadFromHiddenDirectory(Library.java:145)
at model.Model.<init>(Model.java:36)
at controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:39)
at general.DesktopHipster.<init>(DesktopHipster.java:18)
at general.DesktopHipster.main(DesktopHipster.java:26)
```

Comment: Which is line 214? And why the special treatment for a mere TreeSet?

Comment: @EJP `FiltersEnum key = FiltersEnum.valueOf((String) in.readObject());`

Regarding the Set I tried both writeObject and that solution while experimenting with where the primitive data may come from.

Comment: You don't need that 'valueOf()' line at all. Just serialize and deserialize the Enum itself.